# ROWS not returning in Youtube Analytics API?

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I have made a request to this url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports` with the metrics: `likes and dislikes`.

The echoed response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "likes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "dislikes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ]
}
```

Where are the rows and the actual data that i requested? In the documentation this is what is *supposed* to return when i request data from youtube:

```
{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "dataType": string,
      "columnType": string
    },
    ... more headers ...
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      {value}, {value}, ...
    ]
  ]
}
```

But i get no "rows": [] data. Does my account just not have any analytics or did i do something wrong?

If i cange the `alt=json` to `alt=csv` i get `null` returned.

Comment: From the docs: 'If no data is available for the given query, the rows element will be omitted from the response.'

Comment: There must be data, since i have had the channel for a while. And i did span the time for over a year.

Comment: Are you setting the correct channel ID? Do you get the same results using the test form at the end of this page? https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/ I'm not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: Actually, you where correct. Even though i did have recent stats, i changed the time span, then it worked?! I guess there is another issue. Please post your answer above concerning the times. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/): 'If no data is available for the given query, the rows element will be omitted from the response.'