# youtube analytics API v1 - APIs explorer does not return any metrics

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the APIs explorer to call the analytics API.
[See here.](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2017-11-11&metrics=dislikes%252Clikes%252Cviews&fields=columnHeaders%252Ckind%252Crows&_h=2&)

These are the fields filled in:

```
ids:        channel==MINE  
start date: 2016-01-01  
end date:   2017-11-11  
metrics:    dislikes,likes, fields  
fields:     columnHeaders,kind,rows
```

It's able to authenticate successfully, and returns the rowheaders. However, there are no metrics returned as part of the response (see below).
Am I missing something in the parameters?

This post said rows will not be returned if there are no data - [ROWS not returning in Youtube Analytics API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884183/rows-not-returning-in-youtube-analytics-api).

However, I do have one video uploaded to my channel.

```
{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "dislikes",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "likes",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "views",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Use API Explorer instead of Youtube API TRy-it

I ran the link you gave with your parameters filled-in. Authorized and executed it and here's what I got:

[image]

which indicates that you have:

```
0 dislikes
5 likes
98 views
```