# Youtube analytics API v2 returns no rows

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to use Google API explorer https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query to request data which returns no values in rows tag but Youtube analytics dashboard is having values.

Following is the response which I am getting out of API Explorer,

```
200

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "ageGroup",
   "columnType": "DIMENSION",
   "dataType": "STRING"
  },
  {
   "name": "gender",
   "columnType": "DIMENSION",
   "dataType": "STRING"
  },
  {
   "name": "viewerPercentage",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "FLOAT"
  }
 ],
 "rows": [
 ]
}
```

Request URL : https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=ageGroup%2Cgender&endDate=2019-01-31&filters=province%3D%3DUS-CA&ids=channel%3D%3DUCRPwwjkjkjWrX96ef-rhiinyQ&metrics=viewerPercentage&sort=gender%2CageGroup&startDate=2014-05-01&fields=columnHeaders%2Cerrors%2Ckind%2Crows&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I'm clueless and not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Can you add the sample URL request you're using. Also, which data you want request? it is not clear to me.

Comment: Apologies, added sample URL request

Comment: prady, can you confirm this is your channel_id? = `UCRPwwjkjkjWrX96ef-rhiinyQ`  also, try make a request in a closer date range: like `2019-02-01` - `2019-02-12`. I think I had read about historical data, hence my suggestion. Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22886017/4092887).

Comment: Based from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/data_model): '***If no data is available for the given query, the rows element will be omitted from the response.***'

Comment: I tried to authenticate the request using owner account, no results in rows tag but I tried the same using respective brand account, now I could see some data. But how do I fetch data using owner account?